# BreezeJS inlineCount() not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze, entity-framework-6

I have the following query that executes successfully, but data.inlineCount is always the same as data.results.length. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here's the query execution call:

```
manager.executeQuery(query.take(0).inlineCount(true)).then(function (data) {alert(data.inlineCount);});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug having to do with using 'select', 'take' and 'inlineCount' used together.  The fix is currently checked into GitHub and will be part of the 1.4.7 release, out later this week.

Comment: This is great, Jay. I will keep an eye on NuGet for the update to 1.4.7.